# How to quickly mentally calculate large powers for a single digit?

Tags: exponentiation, mental-arithmetic

How do you calculate something like $9^{21}$ in your head quickly? Was asked this during an interview and did not know what is a good way to quickly derive the answer. The actual answer is $1.0941899\times10^{20}$.

Comment: Did you have pen and paper available, or were you actually asked to do it entirely in your head?

Comment: Is that a joke ? This cannot easily be calculated by hand quickly , not even with the given approximation. If someone demonstrates to be able to do this exactly and fast , I would rather think that many powers are just memorized.

Comment: What kind of interview was it? For finance/trading? $\quad$ Did they just want your best approximation, or the exact answer?

Comment: (If you did have pen and paper, there is one well-known technique for calculating relatively large powers relatively quickly. I'd say maybe I could do this one in a minute or three? But I suspect that the question was asked not to see if you could calculate the answer, but rather how you react to a difficult problem that you don't yet know the answer to. This is a very common thing they look for in interviews. Classic alternative questions include "How many piano tuners are there in London?" and "How many ping pong balls do you think could fit in a shipping container?")

Comment: Actually, $9^{21} = 109418989131512359209$. I didn't calculate that by hand or in my head. I would probably have blushed in shame at the interview and then later realised that I should have said that I don't know how to give a precise answer, but I can see that it's between $8^{21}=2^{24}$ and $10^{21}$. Good luck with your interviews!

Comment: $9^{21}=(10-1)^{21}$ You can expand and that should be the easiest way, still nothing you should do in your head though...

Comment: I suppose you might estimate it very roughly and quickly in your
head as
$$
9\times\left(1-\frac1{10}\right)^{20}\!\!\times10^{20} \bumpeq
9\times e^{-2}\times10^{20} \bumpeq 1.1\times10^{20},
$$
because $e\bumpeq2\sqrt2,$ so $e^2 \bumpeq 8.$ I'll get me coat. :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: Thumbs up for your East Cheam address and "I'll get me coat"!  You are clearly a $\Diamond$ geezer. God bless!

Comment: I do get a pen and paper, but I thought it is pretty much impossible to get very high accuracy right there on a spot I would say. I answered approximately $1.1 \times 10^{20}$ just off the top of my head similar to @CalumGilhooley's answer but without the working haha...

Comment: It would be interesting to know what your argument was. My argument only gives a result correct to 2 significant digits because it contains errors in opposite directions - $(9/10)^{10}$ is quite a bit less than $e^{-1},$ while on the other hand, $e^2$ is closer to $7$ than $8$ - which happen to nearly cancel one another out. Was your argument saner than that?